# Transforming reaction-diffusion equations to random walk processes

Tags: pr.probability, random-walks, brownian-motion, lattice-theory, stochastic-differential-equations

I have a two species reaction-diffusion system which is a Turing-type (activator-inhibitor) equation. I am trying to transform my reaction-diffusion system into a system of multiple walkers on a lattice with interactions or with differing jump probabilities.

These are the type of my equations:

[image: An example of an activator-inhibitor system of equations]

I did an extensive search and I found this paper really relevant:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.6494.pdf

I am wondering if anyone here knows any relevant paper or a better way to transform a reaction-diffusion problem into a system of random walkers.

Comment: Could you please specify your initial and/or boundary conditions?  Also, what guarantees the existence of a non-exploding solution to these PDEs?  I am a bit concerned by the $1/h$ nonlinearity.

Comment: It is not quite clear what kind of lattice you are thinking of. Do you want to discretize your space domain? Or are you thinking of a different approximation? There is a paper by Bobrowski (http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00023-012-0158-z) showing that under suitable b.c. and if $p=p'=0$ (so the PDEs are linear and uncoupled - but they are allowed to be coupled at the boundary), the solutions converge to a space-discrete dynamical system as $D_a\to \infty$ and $D_h\to \infty$. It could be worth a try to extend this result to your setting.